# get product category from a product_id Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to check if a specific product belong to a category?

```
public function check_add_to_cart_product() {       
    //Check to see if user has product in cart        
        $targetcatslug = array('indica', 'sativa', 'hybrid');//target categories slug
        $incat=false;
        $terms = get_the_terms( $product_id,'product_cat');

        if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) : 

            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

                $product_cat_slug= $term->slug;
                if($product_cat_slug == $targetcatslug) {
                    $incat = true;
                }
            }
        endif;

        return $incat;
}
```

For example `if $product_id = 456`, I would like to find it category and check if they are belong to categories of ( 'indica','sative','hybrid'). If yes, return true and return false if no. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you are getting the value for $product_id from but if the product id is correctly fetched. You just need to use

`in_array($product_cat_slug, $targetcatslug)`

in your if condition.
make sure you get the product id fetched correctly. Use `var_dump($product_id);` in your code to verify this.
Everything else is seems to be correct in the code.

Let me if this works.